# Show dialog on first start of application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog, messagebox

Is there an easy way to show an dialog when the program is started for the first time (and only the first time), for some kind of instruction or specifying settings?

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? Mvc? Wpf?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could save it as a bool in your settings and you should check at load event of first form.
Your settings file should have a setting that I called "FirstRun" do this with following steps:

1. Right click your Project
2. Click "Properties"
3. Click "Settings" tabpage(probably on the left)
4. Add setting like I did as seen in image above

Note: The `Scope` can be changed to "Application", if that is your application's need, since you didn't mention in your question.

Your Settings file should look like image below:

[image: SettingsFile]

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((bool)Properties.Settings.Default["FirstRun"] == true) 
    {
       //First application run
       //Update setting
       Properties.Settings.Default["FirstRun"] = false;
       //Save setting
       Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
       //Create new instance of Dialog you want to show
       FirstDialogForm fdf = new FirstDialogForm();
       //Show the dialog
       fdf.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
       //Not first time of running application.
    }
}
```

Note: <strike>wrote this from my phone, so I couldn't compile to test</strike>
Edit: Checked code and added image from desktop.

Comment: ok I added the bool, but the if statement shows the error '== cannot be applied to operands of type object and bool' also I guess is should be fdf.ShowDialog()

Comment: Updated question, added the cast at if statement, thanks I'm typing from phone haha, corrected fd to fdf as well:)

Comment: showdialog() method is not found do I need a using directive or sth?

Comment: Did you add a form to your project, named 'FirstDialogForm'? And it needs to be written like 'ShowDialg();' (case sensitive)

Comment: You will need a form(dialog) to show, so if you don't have any yet, add it, right click project -> Add -> new Item... -> Windows Form, then name it FirstDialogForm

Comment: ok now it works, tricky to test if it only shows once :) thank you

Comment: This won't work -- If you are using from `[Designer]`, then you won't be able to experience the `FirstDialog` again. Instead, put it in a button on the next form.

Answer (score 4):

You can have bool value in your settings file which is a "user setting" which means you can change it to true save it for this specific user.
When your application starts just check that value. If it's false show your dialog and change it to true and it will stay true.

```
public void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Settings.Default.ShowDialog) 
    {
       Settings.Default.ShowDialog = false;
       Settings.Default.Save();
       // show first disalog
    }
    // rest of code if needed
}
```

Here's an MSDN link on user settings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I assume you're creating WinForms application. First of all, locate the Load event in your main Form event lists (or simply double click your Form in Designer panel). The following method stub will pop up:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

And modify it like this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your message here");
}
```

Comment: I think he meant the first ever run of the application.

Comment: and this is only for the first use of the application?

Comment: My mistake, this is the first thing that happens when you run the application. But if you want it to occur only the first time a user launches it on a new machine, then follow Max Mommersteeg answer